# Break down of lui MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to figure out how `ori t1,100000` breaks down in MIPS. MIPS says that it becomes .

```
lui $1,1
ori $1,$1,34464
or $9,$9,$1
```

I'm not sure how it got the value 1 for `lui` and 34464 for `ori`.

Comment: Look at it in hex and it's obvious how it uses 2 16-bit immediates to make one 32-bit constant.

Comment: And as always with _"What does this MIPS instruction do?"_-questions; look it up in **MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set**.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert 100000 to hexadecimal with any calculator, you get

> 100000=0x186a0

Its size is superior to 16 bits and in MIPS an immediate cannot be larger than 16 bits. We cannot input this value in one instruction.

Look at the different upper and lower parts.

> 0x186a0=0x10000+0x86a0
>   = (0x1<<16)+0x86a0

and

> 0x86a0=34464

Now we have everything that is required to write the code.

```
# store 0x10000==1<<16 in an intermediate register with lui (load upper immediate)
# MIPS asm uses $1 (or $at) as intermediate register
lui $1,1
# content of $1 is 0x00010000
ori $1,$1,34464
# nor we can OR this register with t1 (also called $9)
or $9,$9,$1
```